# DEVPATH not working in .NET 4.5.2 CLR v4.0.30319

Tags: c#, .net, gac, fusion

During testing I want a dll to be picked from a local folder instead of the GAC. As per [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/12/13/503059.aspx) on web and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cskzh7h6.aspx), using DEVPATH is one of the solutions, but it doesn't seem to work. (I don't want to change the version or remove strong name - which are two alternative ways to solve this issue, as per suggestions at various places).

**Details:**
I have ProductCode.dll which is gac-ed. I made some changes to the source code and I want to test that. I have unit tests written in TestCode.dll. However, during testing (I am using vstest.console.exe on command line), the assembly in the gac gets picked up. I want .NET to pick up the assembly in the local folder instead.

I have set DEVPATH environment variable to:

```
set DEVPATH=C:\temp\NoSysGac\TryingAppDomainsToBypassGac\TestCodeDllAndLatestProductCodeDll
```

I modified machine.config at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config to enable development mode:

```
<runtime>
  <developmentMode developerInstallation="true"/>
</runtime>
```

Then I run tests using:

```
C:\Path\to\vstest.console.exe TestCode.dll
```

But this fails to find the new method I added because it picks up ProductCode.dll from GAC, which is old. I can verify that the modified machine.config does get picked up because the application failed to start when I had a typo in the file.
Fusion also recognizes the DEVPATH value, but still doesn't look there. It just returns the assembly from the gac.

Fusion log:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\te.processhost.managed.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = ProductCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6b6a45a9f6fa2e7a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/temp/NoSysGac/TryingAppDomainsToBypassGac/TestCodeDllAndLatestProductCodeDll
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = te.processhost.managed.exe
Calling assembly : TestCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\te.processhost.managed.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: ProductCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6b6a45a9f6fa2e7a
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ProductCode\v4.0_1.0.0.0__6b6a45a9f6fa2e7a\ProductCode.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Or is DEVPATH [broken](http://weblog.ikvm.net/2012/12/16/AHackToMakeCLRsDEVPATHSuckLess.aspx) in .NET 4.5 too?